# How to Select from SubQuery using distinct in Laravels

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table name "warga" , the table consist:
id (primary key), no_card, name, description.  The no_card is a group from some id.
Then, I will count the description based on no_card.
This is the SQL code :

-SQL code :

```
SELECT description, COUNT(description) as cnt 
FROM ( SELECT distinct no_card, description FROM `warga` ) as t
GROUP by description ;
```

the SQL already show the data that I need, then in the laravels :

```
$data =  DB::table('warga')->selectRaw('description , COUNT(description ) AS CountData')
            ->select('no_card', 'description')->distinct()->from('warga')
            ->groupby('description')
            ->get();
```

When I run the program, the alis table CountData is not detected,
Do you have suggestion to fix it?
Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use subquery tables as closures or passing them as builder objects.

- `DB::table(Closure, alias)` or `DB::query()->from(Closure, alias)`
- `DB::table(Builder, alias)` or `DB::query()->from(Closure, alias)`

```php
$subquery = DB::table('warga')
    ->select('no_card', 'description')
    ->distinct();

$results = DB::table($subquery, 't')
    ->select('description')
    ->selectRaw('count(description) as cnt')
    ->groupBy('description')
    ->get();
```

```php
$results = DB::table(function ($query) {
        $query->from('warga')
            ->select('no_card', 'description')
            ->distinct();
    }, 't')
    ->select('description')
    ->selectRaw('count(description) as cnt')
    ->groupBy('description')
    ->get();
```

You can even make the query look very SQL-like if you want.

```php
$query = DB::query()
    ->select('description')
    ->selectRaw('count(description) as cnt')
    ->from(function ($sub) {
        $sub->select('no_card', 'description')
            ->distinct();
    }, 't')
    ->groupBy('description')
    ->get();
```

Comment: hi, sorry for late reply, the code works well , thanks :)