# Generate "WITH AS" via eloquent using an inner query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

How can I generate the equivalent of this (postgresql) query in eloquent

```
WITH result as (
select *, order_id as alias_id from orders
)
SELECT *
FROM result;
```

I should be able to pass the inner query as eloquent builder query.

Comment: What database is this one? From what I googled, it is Oracle, if that is the case, please add the missing tag...

Comment: It works well with Postgres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comment, Laravel does not support WITH clauses (common table expressions) in its query builder. You can however, pass it in raw.

```php
$query = 'WITH results AS (
    SELECT *, order_id AS alias_id
FROM orders
)
SELECT *
FROM results';

$results = DB::select($query);
```

I mentioned a package in the comment. One I've found that works well enough is [`staudenmeir/laravel-cte`](https://packagist.org/packages/staudenmeir/laravel-cte).
Depending on your laravel version, you might need to install a specific version with  `composer`.

With that package installed, you can formulate your query like this so it looks the most as the original SQL:

```php
$results = DB::query()
    ->withExpression('results', function ($query) { // WITH results AS (
        $query->select('*', 'order_id AS alias_id') //   SELECT *, order_id AS alias_id
            ->from('orders');                       //   FROM orders
    })                                              // )
    ->select('*')                                   // SELECT *
    ->from('results')                               // FROM results
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the CTE (with expression). CTEs are an extension to sub-query concept. Initially so that that it could be reused instead of written for each use. But since you are using it just once a sub-query would be just fine. Your query can be rewritten as:

```
select result.*
  from ( select *, order_id as alias_id 
           from orders
       ) result;
```

From your description I assume sub-query above is the *inner query as eloquent builder query*. Otherwise it reduces to `select *, order_id as alias_id from orders`.  
I do not know Laravel/Eloquent Query Builder but assume it should easily handle a simple sub-query.

Comment: The Laravel query builder can handle subqueries with its `from($table, $as=null)` or `table($table, $as=null)` methods. `$table` can take a string as a value, a `Closure` that has its own query builder injected in or another instance of a query builder with the necessary information to run the subquery.  [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69270563/how-to-select-from-subquery-using-distinct-in-laravels/69270840#69270840)